# Forcing applications (games) to run at a low resolution

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, screen-resolution

I own a Galaxy Nexus and the performance of a few "HD" games is horrible. Even with a bus overclocked kernel from here: http://www.derkernel.com/jb-tuna.php

Is there any way to maybe force apps to run on a lower resolution, say 540x960, without losing my app data? Are there any ROMs out there which allow you to do so?

Comment: Can you name a game that runs horrible on the Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: @Flow GTA3, temple run brave, few levels of N.O.V.A. i'm not saying their performance is unplayable. I personally  would like a constant 60FPS over a few more pixels.

Comment: okay, maybe "horrible" was too harsh. consider it as "below my expectations" from a Rs25000 phone.

Comment: I just wanted to know so that I can compare it myself and if I don't have any problems, chances are that there is something wrong with your device.